# What are the stabilty "factors" of sorting?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Lately, I have been learning about various methods of sorting and a lot of them are **unstable** i.e selection sort, quick sort, heap sort.
*My question is*: What are the general factors that make sorting unstable?

Comment: Anything that can move an element more than one position from where it started is potentially unstable.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm thinking about it, but it's quite vague for me. could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't come up with a good way of expanding that comment into an answer. And I didn't even phrase the comment correctly, obviously an element will need to move more than one position, just not more than one position at a time. My go-to sort, merge sort, is naturally stable so I've never given it a whole lot of thought.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the efficient sorting algorithms are efficient since they move data over a longer distance i.e. far closer to the final position every move. This efficiency causes the loss of stability in sorting. 
For example, when you do a simple sort like bubble sort, you compare and swap neighboring elements. In this case, it is easy to not move the elements if they are already in the correct order. But say in the case of quick-sort, the partitioning process might chose to say move so the swaps are minimal. For example, if you partition the below list on the number 2, the most efficient way would be to swap the 1st element with the 4th element and 2nd element with the 5th element

> 2 3 1 1 1 4
>   1 1 1 2 3 4

If you notice, now we have changed the sequence of 1's in the list causing it to be unstable.

So to sum it up, some algorithms are very suitable for stable sorting (like bubble-sort), whereas some others like quick sort can be made stable by carefully selecting a partitioning algorithm, albeit at the cost of efficiency or complexity or both.

We usually classify the algorithm to be stable or not based on the most "natural" implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

A sorting algorithm is *stable* when it uses the *original order* of elements to break ties in the new ordering.  For example, lets say you have records of `(name, age)` and you want to sort them by age.

If you use a stable sort on `(Matt, 50), (Bob, 20), (Alice, 50)`, then you will get `(Bob, 20), (Matt, 50), (Alice, 50)`.  The Matt and Alice records have equal ages, so they are equal according to the sorting criteria.  The stable sort preserves their original relative order -- Matt came before Alice in the original list, so it comes before Alice in the output.

If you use an unstable sort on the same list, you *might* get `(Bob, 20), (Matt, 50), (Alice, 50)` or you might get `(Bob, 20), (Alice, 50), (Matt, 50)`.  Elements that compare equal will be grouped together but can come out in any order.

It's often handy to have a stable sort, but a stable sort implementation has to remember information about the original order of the elements while its reordering them.

*In-place* array sorting algorithms are designed not to use any extra space to store this kind of information, and they destroy the original ordering while they work.  The fast ones like quicksort aren't usually stable, because reordering the array in ways that preserve the original order to break ties is slow.  Slow array sorting algorithms like insertion sort or selection sort can usually be written to be stable without difficulty.

Sorting algorithms that copy data from one place to another, or work with other data structures like linked lists, can be both fast and stable.  Merge sort is the most common.

Comment: I think the OP knows what is stable sorting but wants to understand what makes any sorting unstable. I don't believe that the "in-place" characteristic plays any role in it. Also, not sure what "reordering the array in ways that preserve the original order **to break ties** is slow"

Comment: To support "reordering in ways that preserve the original order to break ties is slow", I offer evidence:  All of the stable in-place sorts I know of require O(N^2) swaps, while the unstable ones can sort with expected N log N swaps.  If you take an algorithm like selection sort and make it stable, you will end up with O(N^2) swaps and moves instead of the O(N) you started with.

Comment: To support the comment about in-place sorts...  It's easy to make quicksort stable if you put the partitions in a different array.  It's also easy if you're willing to spend O(N^2) swaps, but then it's not fast

Answer (score 0):

If you have an example input of

> > 1 5 3 7 1

You want for to be stable the last `1` to never go before the first `1`.

Generally, elements with the same value in the input array to not have changed their positions once sorted.

Then sorted would look like:

> > 1(f) 3 5 7 1(l)

f: first, l: last(or second if more than 2).

For example, QuickSort uses swaps and because the comparisons are done with greater *than* (>=) or less *than*, equally valued elements can be swapped while sorting. And as result in the output.

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD Since you are (relatively) new here, you might want to check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: It's not enough to require elements to maintain their order after sorting, they also need to maintain their order *before* sorting.

Comment: Yes, of course, I haven't thought much of the heap, while answering. I assumed array.